# PetaPoco: Fetching into composite object

Tags: c#, petapoco

I'm familiarizing with PetaPoco (it looks great btw), but have one blocker here, and I'm curious if I can do that in PetaPoco.

What I would like to do, is to map one row in the database into a composite object.
I think that example will clear things up.

Suppose, we have a table in the database called 'Customers' and row looks somethins like this:

```
ID | Name     | City     | Street           | 
1  | John Doe | New York | Some Street Name |
```

and I would like to use model like that:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

So we have to different objects in c#, but it's only one entity (one Id, one row in the database).

Can I achieve such mapping using PetaPoco ?

Comment: Sounds like a volcano in Mexico. I can't keep up with all these new technologies with ever-increasing cute names <g>

Comment: Where do you store the address data? If you store it in the DB, why aren't you using an id for the Address?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, it's as simple as:

```
var customers = db.Fetch<customer, address>(@"
        SELECT * FROM customers
        LEFT JOIN adresses ON customers.customerID = adresses.customerID 
        ORDER BY customers.customerID
        ");
```

More info on that and other multimappings in http://www.toptensoftware.com/blog/posts/115-PetaPoco-Mapping-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-One-Relationships

Comment: Solution you are presenting is using two tables (standard relation by id). What I would like to achieve in my question is two have only one table in the database for this and two object on C# side (Address in this example don't have id at all). Thx!